# FileNotFoundError when using gspread

Tags: python, gspread

I am trying to make a program that can add user inputs into a google sheet so I can document it. I have had smooth sailing up until now. I am following [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnPlKLEGR7E) tutorial. Now when I run my code it outputs the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'creds.json'
```

Here is the code I am running

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sprea...',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive...","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

The file it titled "creds.json" and I currently have it sitting on my desktop (Could this be the issue?)

Thank-you for your help!

Comment: The code expects the file to be in the _current directory_, but it is not there.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm new to programming but I have also tried running it with the full file address -> C:\Users\ ___\OneDrive\Desktop\creds.json 
Is this what you were talking about or something different?

Comment: When you tried with the full file path, what happened?  Did you still get the file not found error?

Comment: Error was `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Comment: That's because you have `\U` in the filename, which is special escape sequence.  Use forward slashes instead of backslashes.  Yes, they work on Windows.

Comment: Just tried this, now the unicode error is gone but I'm getting the same error as I had at the start...
Edited code: `creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("C:/Users/ ___/OneDrive/Desktop/creds.json", scope)`

Comment: Then the path must actually be wrong. The file really isn't there.  The only advice i can give is to triple-check the path name to make _sure_ it is correct.

Comment: Thank-you so much for you help, I will check over it some more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `gspread` and authenticate with a service account you can simply follow the [documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account)

The function `service_account` takes the file path of the service account JSON file and returns the client ready to use.

Like so:

```py
gc = gspread.service_account("./my_ceeds.json")

sh = gc.open("Example spreadsheet")

print(sh.sheet1.get('A1'))
```